# Adding multiline string to a Yaml-cpp node

Tags: yaml-cpp

How to add a multi line string as value to key using node ?
I don't want to use emitter.

I want something like below code

Iphone:
   blah ... blah  \n
   blah .... blah \n

I want to create the data similar to above programitically using a YAML::Node object.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the string in your node:

```
YAML::Node node;
node["iphone"] = "blah ... blah \n blah .... blah \n"
std::cout << node;
```

If you're looking to have it output with multiple lines, instead of `\n`, you'll have to use an emitter; yaml-cpp doesn't support formatting output with basic node dumping. (Feel free to file an issue on the project page if you think it's worthwhile.)

Comment: Yes, I am looking a way to add multi line string to a node directly rather than using emitter. Is it possible to get convert a emitter to node ?

Comment: @user3389312, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean creating a YAML::Emitter with string literal data, so that the new lines are retained and final pass that emitter to node.

Comment: What do you mean "final pass that emitter to node"?

Comment: I meant to convert the emitter as a node

Comment: You can't convert an emitter to a node (this wouldn't make sense). What do you mean "as" a node?

Comment: Sorry for bad english :)

Comment: I meant to emitter to node conversion, which you said it is not possible at the moment.

Comment: Is it possible to sequence of nodes to a node using node object ?

Comment: Sorry, the language barrier is making this a bit difficult :)

Comment: I still am not sure what you're saying, but I'm guessing what you want isn't possible - you'll just have to use an `Emitter`.